# graficas en html php

Tags: chart.js, gráficas

Tengo esta gráfica que muestra una barra solamente. ¿Cómo puedo colocarle otras dos barras al lateral de esta y que esta cambie sus colores dependiendo si el data es menor que 50 sea rojo y mayor de 50 sea azul?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
labels: ['Risk Level'],
datasets: [
  {
    label: 'Low',
    data: [67.8],
    backgroundColor: '#D6E9C6',
  },
  {
    label: 'Moderate',
    data: [20.7],
    backgroundColor: '#FAEBCC',
  },
  {
    label: 'High',
    data: [11.4],
    backgroundColor: '#EBCCD1',
  }
  ]
  },
  options: {
  scales: {
  xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
  yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
  }
  }
  });
```

```css
canvas { background-color : #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas id="chart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas agregar otro label en el array de labels:

```
labels: ['Risk Level', 'Risk Level 2'],
```

Y en la parte del `dataset` necesitas agregar el valor en `data` para que se refleje en la gráfica.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
labels: ['Risk Level', 'Risk Level 2'],
datasets: [
  {
    label: 'Low',
    data: [67.8, 50],
    backgroundColor: '#D6E9C6',
  },
  {
    label: 'Moderate',
    data: [20.7, 10],
    backgroundColor: '#FAEBCC',
  },
  {
    label: 'High',
    data: [11.4, 5],
    backgroundColor: '#EBCCD1',
  }
  ],
  },
  options: {
  scales: {
  xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
  yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
  }
  }
  });
```

```css
canvas { background-color : #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas id="chart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: COMO PUEDO PONER UN IF PARA QUE ME PINTE DE UN COLOR CADA CAMPO DE LA BARRA  DEPENDIENDO DEL VALOR DEL DATA?

Comment: Tendrias que validar antes de poner los valores en el dataset segun el valor, el color que pretendes dibujar.